# How to root Huawei Y3II L02 4G

Tags: rooting, 5.1-lollipop, huawei, 4g

How do I root my Huawei Y3II and when would a method be available for my device

Comment: If a rooting method isn't already available, how do you think we'd be able to predict its availability?

Answer (score 0):

For Huawei phones, KingRoot works best, you download the KingRoot app from the internet and try cloud based rooting (internet required). Check if this method works